# how to get data with scrapy which are visible in inspect but not in page source

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

[Site to be scraped](https://in.seamsfriendly.com/products/dusk-beige-warm-cotton-corduroy-baggy-shorts)

[image: I want to scrape name of all 3 colors]
[image: Dusk Beige is visible in inspect but not in page source]

[image]

I want to scrape name of all 3 colors. They are visible in inspect but not in source.
So I thought it's dynamic issue. Playwight can't be used in windows. So I used selenium

```
SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'chrome'
SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = 'F:\Projects\scrapspider\scrapeseams\chromedriver.exe'
SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS=['-headless']  # '--headless' if using chrome instead of firefox
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800
}
```

in `settings.py`

```
  def __init__(self):
        s = Service('F:\Projects\scrapspider\scrapeseams\chromedriver.exe')
        #driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
       # settings = get_project_settings()
       # driver_path = settings['SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH']
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s,options=chrome_options)
    def start_requests(self):
        
        yield SeleniumRequest(
            url = "https://in.seamsfriendly.com/collections/shorts",
            wait_time = 3,
            screenshot = True,
            callback = self.parse1,
            dont_filter = True
        )
```

this is my spider file.

but I'm getting error- `TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'`

**How do I get all 3 names?** I got other infos as they were available but not this one.

*update* if I don't use middleware I'm not getting error(executable) but also not getting those 3 names

```
response.xpath("//div[@class='swatch-navigable-wrapper']/p/text()").getall()
```

this is how I'm trying to get